# Shifting a char value by 24 bits

Tags: c, bit-shift

```
static unsigned int read24(unsigned char *ptr)
{
  unsigned char b0;
  unsigned char b1;
  unsigned int  b2;

  b0 = *ptr++;     //b0 = 00            
  b1 = *ptr++;     //b1 = AA
  b2 = *ptr;       //b2 = BB

  b0 = (b0 & 0x000000ff) ; 
  b1 = (b1 << 8) & 0x0000ff00);
  b2 = (b2 & 0x000000ff) << 16;

  return (b0 | b1 | b2) ;  
}
```

code 2

```
static unsigned int read24(unsigned char *ptr)
{
  unsigned char b0;
  unsigned char b1;
  unsigned char b2;

  b0 = *ptr++;
  b1 = *ptr++;
  b2 = *ptr;

  return (
       ((b0 & 0x000000ff)) |
       ((b1 & 0x000000ff) << 8 |
       ((b2 << 16) & 0x00ff0000) |
     );
}
```

Here I am confused about the shifting operation done with `b1` and `b2`. Will shifting a char `b1` by 8 or more than 8 make the value zero?
What is a better strategy,first shifting and then anding or first anding and then shifting. I want a return value which should be BBAA00. Have I done the right thing?

In case I am wrong ..is the second code correct?

Comment: There is no sense in masking in this case. Also, `b1` (and better also `b0`) shall be of `int` type, not char.

Answer (score 4):

The asymmetry in the handling of the shift-by-8 and shift-by-16 is odd, but harmless as long as `sizeof(int) >= 2` (assuming `CHAR_BIT == 8`).  The masking is all a little odd; the intention is probably to ensure that that the shift is done on a larger type, which is guaranteed since the operands are converted to `int`.  However, the assignments back to `b0`, `b1`, and `b2` undo any good that was done; `b0` is unchanged, and the other two are zeroed.

The code should probably be more like this:

```
static unsigned int read24(unsigned char *ptr)
{
    unsigned char b0;
    unsigned char b1;
    unsigned int  b2;  // assert(sizeof(b2) >= 4);

    b0 = *ptr++;     //b0 = 00            
    b1 = *ptr++;     //b1 = AA
    b2 = *ptr;       //b2 = BB

    b2 <<= 16;
    b2  |= (b1 << 8) & 0xFF00;  // Mask only necessary if sizeof(int) == 2
    b2  |= b0;

    return  b2;  
}
```

It could perfectly well be written more compactly as:

```
static unsigned int read24(unsigned char *ptr)
{
    unsigned char b0 = *ptr++;
    unsigned char b1 = *ptr++;
    unsigned int  b2 = *ptr;    // assert(sizeof(b2) >= 4);

    return (b2 << 16) | (b1 << 8) | b0;
}
```

#### Code 2

Your second code fragment is almost correct, but the return expression is wrong.  It is:

```
return (
     ((b0 & 0x000000ff)) |
     ((b1 & 0x000000ff) << 8 |     // Missing )
     ((b2 << 16) & 0x00ff0000) |   // Extraneous |
   );
```

It should be:

```
static unsigned int read24(unsigned char *ptr)
{
    unsigned char b0 = *ptr++;
    unsigned char b1 = *ptr++;
    unsigned char b2 = *ptr;

    return (
        ((b0 & 0x00FF)) |
        ((b1 & 0x00FF) << 8) |
        ((b2 << 16) & 0x00FF0000));
}
```

There was a missing parenthesis and an extraneous `|` in the return expression.  If going down this route, I'd use:

```
static unsigned int read24(unsigned char *ptr)
{
    unsigned char b0 = *ptr++;
    unsigned char b1 = *ptr++;
    unsigned char b2 = *ptr;

    assert(sizeof(int) >= 4);

    return (
        ((b0 <<  0) & 0x0000FF) |
        ((b1 <<  8) & 0x00FF00) |       // 0xFF00 instead of 0x00FF!
        ((b2 << 16) & 0xFF0000));
}
```

This preserves the symmetries.  The `<< 0` will be optimized to a no-op, of course, even without optimization turned on.

#### Is `b1 << 8` undefined behaviour?

Since people seem to be under the illusion that `b1 << 8` is undefined behaviour when `b1` is an `unsigned char`, let me quote the standard:

> ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §6.5.7 **Shift operators**
>
> ¶3 The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand. If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.
>
> ¶4 The result of `E1 << E2` is `E1` left-shifted `E2` bit positions; vacated bits are filled with
>   zeros. If `E1` has an unsigned type, the value of the result is `E1 × 2`<sup>`E2`</sup>, reduced modulo
>   one more than the maximum value representable in the result type. If `E1` has a signed
>   type and non-negative value, and `E1 × 2`<sup>`E2`</sup> is representable in the result type, then that is
>   the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

So, the `unsigned char` is promoted to `int` before the shift occurs (hence my comment about `sizeof(int) >= 2`).  If `sizeof(int) == 2`, then left-shifting a value in `b1` in the range 0x80..0xFF leads to undefined behaviour (UB).  You'd have to decide whether the risk is acceptable, or you'd cast `b1` to `unsigned` before shifting:

```
(unsigned)b1 << 8
```

In the original code:

```
b1 = (b1 << 8) & 0x0000ff00);
```

(which does not compile: it should be `b1 = (b1 << 8) & 0x0000ff00;`!), it is the assignment that does the damage (leaving the result as zero), not the shift.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is UB `b1 << 8`. Is it not?

Comment: @luk32: Why do you think `b1 << 8` is UB?  Have you forgotten about the default promotion rules?

Comment: Don't they work only for arithmetic operations, or `b1` will get promoted to `int`?

Comment: Bitshifting promotes its operands to `int`.  As long as `sizeof(int) > sizeof(char)` then `int x; x << sizeof(char)` is defined behavior. Would be more accurate if there was a `sizeofinbits()` operator but alas there is not.

Comment: @luk32: ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §6.5.7 **Shift operators**: ¶2 _The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The type of the result is
that of the promoted left operand._  So, the `unsigned char` is promoted to `int` before the shift occurs.  Hence my comment about `sizeof(int) >= 2`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks, of course I removed my answer as it would be redunant to yours after a correcting edit. Thanks for all clarifications.I hope I am not the only one stupid enough to be caught by it, so I think the quote is useful and relevant.

Comment: @jonathan - size of int in my case is 4 bytes

Comment: @tapanchawda: OK; `sizeof(int) == 4` is normal for a 32-bit or 64-bit system.  There are a few 16-bit systems around (numerically, in large quantities embedded in hardware of various sorts), but not on the desktop any more.

Comment: `b1 << 8` _could_ have been UB if b1 was a signed type or the default `char` type (with impl.defined signedness). In the case where it is a signed type and contains a negative value, left shifting could indeed invoke UB, if data is shifted into the sign bits. It is important to always be explicit about types when shifting, there exists very few cases where you actually want to do bit shifting on signed types. Better to explicitly cast to an unsigned type than to let C implicitly integer promote into a signed one.

Comment: @Lundin: but `b1` was an `unsigned char` and all the explicit types are unsigned, so the only risk of UB is if `sizeof(int) == 2`, and only the most determinedly cussed compiler writer would break sanely working code.  Frankly, there comes a point at which the 'optimization' is actually a pessimization — the desire to wring the utmost out of the system works to the detriment of the users of the compiler.  In this case, since `sizeof(int) == 4`, there is no risk of UB.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, there is no UB in the code you've posted (it is a good answer). I'm just pointing out how easily it could turn into UB though: simply change `unsigned char` to `char` and the first byte with negative data encountered will invoke UB. Because int promotion will preserve the sign bit. As a rule of thumb, never rely on implicit promotion. Instead of writing `b1 << 8` I would write `(unsigned int)b1 << 8`.

Answer (score 0):

During bit shifting the operands are promoted to `int`. So the left shift of 8 bits works fine. But when we assign it back to `char` from `int` it gets truncated to 1 byte (Size of `char` is 1 byte, so if you left shift by 8 bits the value turns to be 0). So change the data type of `b1` to `int`.

Code 1:Without assignment

```
static unsigned int read24(unsigned char *ptr)
{
unsigned char b0;
unsigned char b1;
unsigned int b2;

b0 = *ptr++;     //b0 = 00            
b1 = *ptr++;     //b1 = AA
b2 = *ptr;       //b2 = BB

return (b0 | (b1<<8) | (b2<<16)) ;  
}
```

code 2: with assignment

```
static unsigned int read24(unsigned char *ptr)
{
unsigned char b0;
unsigned int b1;
unsigned int b2;

b0 = *ptr++;     //b0 = 00            
b1 = *ptr++;     //b1 = AA
b2 = *ptr;       //b2 = BB

b0 = (b0 & 0x000000ff) ; 
b1 = (b1 << 8) & 0x0000ff00);
b2 = (b2 & 0x000000ff) << 16;

return (b0 | b1 | b2) ;  


}
```

Comment: Operand promotion says otherwise.

Comment: Sorry, but the information in this answer is incorrect.  `b1 << 8` is only 0 if `b1` is 0 before the shift.  Otherwise, `b1` is promoted to `int` before the shifting occurs; the result of the shift is also an `int`.  The assignment back to `b1` does then truncate the value if `b1` is `unsigned char`, but it is the assignment, not the shift, that does the damage.

Comment: The mask assignment to `b0` is harmless but pointless unless `CHARBIT > 8`.  You have copied the unbalanced parenthesis from the question into the shift/mask assignment to `b1`.  I'm not convinced there are circumstances where the mask in the assignment to `b1` is helpful. The mask operation on `b2` is unnecessary, but harmless.